# How to delete all records in database without using ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Could you please help me with the following issue?

In my project the website's admin user should be allowed to empty the database by clicking a button. But that would not suppose also modifying the schema. The database contains a set of tables having multiple foreign-key relationships between one another. I have decided not to opt for cascading on delete in order to avoid losing necessary data.

This is a piece of my code:

```
db.Posturi.RemoveRange(db.Posturi.ToList());
db.NumereRezervate.RemoveRange(db.NumereRezervate.ToList());
db.SaveChanges();
```

By now I am getting errors because of the foreign keys:

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Users.stergere.SaveChanges(DbContext context) in D:\INTUIT\Daily Business\Users\Users\stergere.aspx.cs:line 135
   at Users.stergere.callPnl_Callback(Object sender, CallbackEventArgsBase e) in D:\INTUIT\Daily Business\Users\Users\stergere.aspx.cs:line 96
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallbackPanel.OnCallback(CallbackEventArgsBase e)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallbackPanel.RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxWebControl.System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

How can I delete the records in such case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you include the error in the question? I suspect that you try to delete records in a table which are still being referenced by some records in another table. You need to delete all references first.

Comment: make sure that you remove first the deepest level of hierarchy so dependency error will be avoided

Comment: Say you are deleting entries from TableA and TableB has a foreign key coloumn referencing TableA. Does the column holding FKs is nullable column? If it is then EF will automatically set related FK columns to null providing you have loaded TableB entites into context before saveChanges.

Comment: @Hendry I added the error.

Comment: @RaviTeja what do you mean by "loading TableB entities into context"? I already have a line for removing range in each table before calling SaveChanges.

Comment: There's no generic way to do this since in some schemas there may be mutually referencing foreign keys and other such cyclic setups. You need to do something for your *specific* schema which may involve a series of `UPDATE`s to disentangle tables before you can actually perform deletes.